# dump from phpMyAdmin syntax error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

So I am getting error from a CREATE TABLE even though that command is a dump from phpMyAdmin. I exported the the database and is trying to modify the structure through a text editor instead. I have not modified this command in anyway ( I have modified other parts). If I remove this CREATE TABLE then importing the .sql file goes through without a problem.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered removing the charcters referred to in the error message? Try deleting the `--6` just before the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: The error message looks pretty explicit... show us the actual file contents, not a screenshot.

Comment: @JimGarrison sorry, forgot to paste the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `--6` in front of `CREATE TABLE` statement

```sql
--6 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `owner` ( ...
^^^^
```

Should be just

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `owner` ( ...
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69052)** demo

Comment: Didn't know that there should be space after '--'! Thanks

Comment: I will, but I have to wait for 2 minutes more minutes before I can accept it.